# Docker not showing default page

Tags: linux, tomcat, docker

I am using Docker, freshly installed on my Ubuntu. I tried to run the hello-world container and worked fine.
I am trying to use a tomcat server on running :

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:8.0
```

But I can't see any webpage  on my localhost.
Otherwise, I see it works when I launch the `ps` command :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ce51e081bb36        tomcat:8.0          "catalina.sh run"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8888->8080/tcp   berserk_pare
```

I don't understand why it is not working. It's my very first time on Docker and I don't understand it very well.

Comment: Are you running docker natively on the same host where browser is running ? Perhaps you are using docker toolbox, kitematic or virtualbox ?

Comment: Are you connecting to 8888 ?

Comment: Hello, I installed it with docker-engine (like presented in the docs, for ubuntu 15.10). But didn't change any options. Just run the hello-world container, then tomcat... Trying to connect on http://127.0.0.1:8888/, keep loading until error.

Comment: Do you use ufw or any other firewall ? https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#enable-ufw-forwarding
Also try accessing it via it's own dynamic IP address:
1. Find out IP address
`docker inspect ce51e081bb36 | grep IPAddress`
2. telnet container-ip 8080

Comment: It works when I add the docker group on my user. I would prefer not to use it but.. it works. Thank you for your help.